# Creating Navigation in React: Linking Navbar Login Button to Login Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I need help understanding how to set up navigation from the `Navbar` login button to the `Login` page using React-Router.

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './comp/Header';
import Howitworks from './comp/Howitworks';  
import About from './comp/About';
import Agent from './comp/Agent';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      <Howitworks/>
      <About/> 
      <Agent/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <>
    <App />
  </>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Header.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
function Header() {
  return (
    <div className='header'>
        <Navbar/>
        <div className='intro'>
            <p>Looking for a Property !</p>
            <h1><span>Buy </span>and<span> Sell</span> Properties</h1>
            <p className='details'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, quae?<br/> by Hemdan</p>
            <a href='#' className='header-btn'>Details</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Header;
```

Navbar.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from '../images/logo1.png';

function Navbar() {
  return (
    <nav>
        <a href='#' className='logo'>
        <img src={logo} alt='logo' />
        </a>
        <input className='menu-btn' type='checkbox' id='menu-btn'/>
        <label className='menu-icon' for='menu-btn'>
            <span className='nav-icon'></span>
        </label>
        <ul className='menu'>
            <li><a href='#'className='active'>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Sell</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Buy</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href='#' className='property'>Login</a>
        
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Navbar;
```

Despite trying various solutions in the browser, I've struggled to find the correct one for my React navigation issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly suggest starting in the React-Router [Tutorial](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial) and reading over the official documentation, but at a minimum you need 3 things.

1. A router component to provide a routing context and handle navigation actions
2. Routes to navigate to
3. Link components or navigation function to effect navigation actions to routes.

Example:

App - Import a router and render the page content on specific routes.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './comp/Header';
import Howitworks from './comp/Howitworks';  
import About from './comp/About';
import Agent from './comp/Agent';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={/* home page */} />
          <Route path="/howitworks" element={<Howitworks />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/buy" element={<Agent />} />
          <Route path="/sell" element={<Agent />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={/* log-in page */} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Navbar - Import and render `Link` components instead of raw anchor tags.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import logo from '../images/logo1.png';

function Navbar() {
  return (
    <nav>
      <Link to='/' className='logo'>
        <img src={logo} alt='logo' />
      </Link>
      <input className='menu-btn' type='checkbox' id='menu-btn' />
      <label className='menu-icon' for='menu-btn'>
        <span className='nav-icon'></span>
      </label>
      <ul className='menu'>
        <li><Link to='/' className='active'>Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='/about'>About</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='/sell'>Sell</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='/buy'>Buy</Link></li>
      </ul>
      <Link to='/login' className='property'>Login</Link>
    </nav>
  );
}
```